# How to determine if an unmounted CD/DVD is in the drive?

Tags: linux, devices, dvd, data-cd

Under Linux, is there any way to get a yes/no answer to whether or a CD/DVD drive contains a disc which isn't mounted but which can be mounted or written to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use blkid to get the info of a possible mounted block device:

```
blkid
```

It will output something like:

```
/dev/sr0: UUID="2013-05-31-23-04-19-00" LABEL="Blah" TYPE="iso9660" PTTYPE="dos"
[root@arch32-vm ~]# echo $?
0
```

If empty will output 2.

Answer (score -1):

If there is just one drive, you could call

```
cdrecord -v -minfo
```

If there is a medium inside, you get the media information.

If there is no medium inside, you get an error message with no media.

If you have more than one drive, you need to specify the `dev=` parameter, see man page: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/cdrecord.1.html

Comment: Is cdrecord standart?

Comment: My version of wodim (1.1.11) says that `-minfo` is a bad option.

Comment: woidm is a dead fork that is on a state from 2004 and full of wodim-specific bugs, better use the original software.

Comment: cdrecord is available for all platforms, what do you call standard?